# Magento create new field type for admin module

Tags: php, magento

in a custom module with admin pages, in the file
app\code\local\Namespace\Mymodulw\Block\Myblock\Edit\Tab\Form.php
you can add somthing like this

```
$fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Title'),
        'class'     => 'required-entry',
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'title',
    ));
```

this create an input of type text in the edit page, what i'm trying to do is create a new type, then i can make something like this

```
$fieldset->addField('title', 'mytype', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Title'),
        'class'     => 'required-entry',
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'title',
    ));
```

can you see the diference??
thanks

Comment: Mage::helper('mymodule') *to* Mage::helper('**Mymodule**') ????

Comment: Yes? The code is different. Is there another question you wanted to ask?

Comment: sorry about that erro, but isn't what i'm talking, is this

Comment: sorry for that error, addField('title', 'text' to $fieldset->addField('title', 'mytype',

Comment: yeah, the code is diference, lol, but my question is how to create a custom field type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adminhtml field types extend `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract` and are located in `\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element`.  So you would need to create a new file called `Mytype.php` with a declaration of `class Varien_Data_Form_Element_Mytype extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract` and then override the Abstract methods to function as you need.

Check out the files in that directory for examples.

Cheers,
JD

Comment: thanks, really help me, although i'm stuck creating my first one

Comment: For others needing this, you probably want addElement rather than addField. e.g.

`
$element = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mytype');
if ($renderer = Varien_Data_Form::getFieldsetElementRenderer())     $element->setRenderer($renderer);
$element->setName('my_field')
            ->setLabel('My Field')
            ;
`

Comment: Jonathon, I am very late to this answer but is this applciable for Magento2? I can't find `lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element` so I guess Magento has moved on, is there a new wy way to do this now?